# Facing error when running test cases using rspeck mock

Tags: testing, rspec, mocking

I was checking mock documentation and i had read somewhere that I can use "..." as a parameter, but when I try to use it I receive an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxpKH.png)

This is the code that's returning this error:

```
require_relative '../../lib/random_joke'

describe JokeMessage do
  let(:bot) { double }
  let(:api) { double }
  let(:message) { double }

  it 'fires send_message' do
    expect(bot).to receive(:api).and_return(api)
    expect(api).to receive(:send_message).with(...)
    described_class.new(bot: bot, message: message).send_response
  end
end
```

Following the documentation "..." should work. I don't get what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You have to list the expected arguments inside with(). If it is the case that you do not want to check for arguments just leave out with or for a catch-all argument use the keyword [any_args](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.5/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers.html) .

Comment: I tried with(no_args) and received the following error:
Failures:

  1) JokeMessage fires send_message
     Failure/Error: bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "What's your name?")
       #<Double (anonymous)> received unexpected message :chat with (no args)

Am I using it wrong?
any_args will return the same error

Comment: The problem is that you have to expect to receive the method `chat` I think.